# Facebook - embed a video in a wall post that also has another link

Tags: php, facebook

I have researched previous answers and found a similar question with the same title. However - this was 3 years ago and Facebook api etc has changed since....SO the question is - does anyone know how I can post a video to a wall - and include a link with it which will redirect when the video is clicked.

My code to do the post is;

```
$linkData = [
    'source' => new \CURLFile($mergepath, ''.$media.''),
    'title' => ''.$title.'',
    'description' => $description
    ];

    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', $linkData);
```

which does work....and shows the video at $mergepath on the wall

If I add a link => with a URL to it - it still works but clicking the video only causes it to start - and not redirect??

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: So in other words, you're trying to trick people into visiting a web site when they are trying to watch a video?

Comment: No of course not - it will be quite clear to them what the click thru is for and their choice whether to. I thought this was a technical forum not a philosophical and morality debate!!